# Google Firestore find deleted subcollections for a deleted document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

When I go to delete a document from the Firestore console,  I get the following message:
"This will permanently delete all data at this location, including all nested data."

However, the Firestore documentation reads: "Deleting a document does not delete the documents in its subcollections"

Can someone clarify this relationship for me?

If I delete a document from the Firestore console, it appears to remove all subcollections and nested data. If it doesn't, how can I delete said sub collections since I can no longer see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console will do exactly what it says - delete the document and all of the subcollections organized under it.

The client APIs will not.  If you delete a document using the standard `delete()` method on a document reference, it will not delete anything organized under it.